# Request timeout when testing an express checkout integration

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox

this is my first time using the PayPal API, I'm trying to test the express checkout integration in a java web application with a sandbox account, and I'm having problems in the first step. I'm calling the SetExpressCheckout operation and I get this error:
 "TIMESTAMP=2014%2d11%2d25T15%3a19%3a14Z&CORRELATIONID=523b6bcbe502f&ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=10001&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Internal%20Error&**L_LONGMESSAGE0=Timeout%20processing%20request**"

As you can see in L_LONGMESSAGE0 the description is "Timeout processing request" and, I don't know if it's related, but the TIMESTAMP is 3 hours ahead (I'm in GMT-3, so when I sent the request it was 12:19:14 instead of 15:19:14). Besides this, I'm building my url according to PayPal's help, here is a sample (using the default test user, password and signature provided for the sandbox account):

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?USER=sdk-three_api1.sdk.com&PWD=QFZCWN5HZM8VBG7Q&SIGNATURE=A-IzJhZZjhg29XQ2qnhapuwxIDzyAZQ92FRP5dqBzVesOkzbdUONzmOU&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=99.0&RETURNURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fmysite%2Fsomepage&CANCELURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%mysite%2Ferror&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=10.00
```

and this is the full code:

```
String sUrl = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?USER=sdk-three_api1.sdk.com&...."; //the full URL shown above
URL obj = new URL(sUrl);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer sbResponse = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    sbResponse.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

Every time I read the response, I see that "Timeout processing request" message (I also tried without encoding the request parameters, same result). Does anybody knows what's going on here, or at least a tip so I can check it?. Most of the posts I've found related to this error are for php and caused by problems in the parameters (bad encoding, missing parameters, etc).
Thanks in advance, regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that paypal doesn't like the url in the way I wrote it, so I've changed the `HttpURLConnection` for `org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost`, so this is my code (working):

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SANBOX_URL);
    post.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"); 
    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(USER, "SANDBOX_USER"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PASSWORD, "SANDBOX_PWD"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SIGNATURE, "SANDBOX_SIGNATURE"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(VERSION, "VERSION"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(ACTION, "ACTION"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(AMOUNT, "AMOUNT"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(RETURN_URL, "RETURN_URL"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(CANCEL_URL, "CANCEL_URL"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(METHOD, "METHOD"));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Another thing I had to change, was not encode the values of the parameters; once I did all of this changes, finally I've got "TOKEN=XXXX&TIMESTAMP=2014%2d11%2d27T00%3a08%3a29Z&CORRELATIONID=XXXX&ACK=Success&VERSION=119%2e0&BUILD=XXXX".

Hope it helps someone else